# http request within Observable happens even without subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs6

I'm seeing the http request happen - in the Chrome Network tab, and also by using `then()` within the fetch promise - with the below code, despite never subscribing to the inner observable (`saveCourses$`).

I modified to use `from()` rather than `fromPromise()` as per the updated rxjs documentation, but the same occurs.

My understanding is that the inner Observable should not run?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(() => this.form.valid)
  )
    .subscribe(changes => {
      const saveCourses$ = fromPromise(fetch(`/api/courses/${this.course.id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(changes),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      }));
    });
}
```

Comment: The `fromPromise` method is most likely using the promise right away in order to convert it into an observable. Why aren't you using the built in Angular http stuff that does things the way you are wanting?

Comment: I'm following an Angular University course on rxjs - I don't intend to use fetch in any projects, but for this example I understand the http request shouldn't be happening without the subscription (according to the course author who hasn't yet come back to me). I'd really like to understand why this auto subscription is happening

Comment: As stated, it is happening in the `fromPromise` code. The callback passed to the `Observable` in the code is calling the `then` method right away. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/de9d2e4cef759b358c6c5d53b85e337dbf1c9c45/src/internal/observable/fromPromise.ts#L8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is common for Observable-based interfaces to defer expensive work (like network calls) until they are *subscribed*, that's not strictly necessarily. Sometimes, a method that returns an Observable will already have done, or begun, a lot of work even before its [subscribe](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) method is called. If the Observable does work before its is subscribed, it's often referred to as "hot" (as opposed to "cold" Observables that don't do work unless subscribers are attached). See the ["Hot and Cold Observables"](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) section here.

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-based interfaces work a lot like "hot" Observables. That is, we expect that the potentially expensive operation will be started as soon as we call the function that gives us the Promise. We learn about the result of the operation when the Promise is resolved, but it will resolve whether or not we actually listen to it (i.e., hook up a "then" handler to the Promise).

In your example, your Observable is *created* with the `fromPromise` method:

```
fromPromise(fetch(`/api/courses/${this.course.id}`...)
```

fromPromise works, essentially, by waiting for a Promise to be resolved, and when it is, emitting the Promise's resolved value via a newly-created Observable. The important thing here is that `fromPromise` *has to call fetch()* in order to get the Promise from which the Observable is built. And the act of calling fetch causes the network call to be initiated.

So in this case, but unlike most "typical" uses of Observables for network or other long operations, you needn't call .subscribe() for the operation to be executed. It will execute as soon as `fetch` is called, and `fetch` is called when the Observable is *created*, not when *subscribed*.

Comment: thanks for the clear and detailed explanation. One more quick point - I created a function that calls fetch within an Observable.create() method, and the http request is in that case NOT triggered unless I explicitly subscribe - so this means it is in particular the combination of fromPromise and fetch that causes the problem in the original question, rather than just using fetch, is that correct?

Comment: @DJC Right, the difference is that the function that you pass to `Observable.create` is only called when the Observable is *subscribed*. Contrast this with the behavior of `fromPromise`, with which the supplied function is called when the Observable is *created*. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html

Comment: Perfect - thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Turns out Angular University got it wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `fetch` and use `HttpClient`. If you open a console and type `fetch('foo')` you will see a net request. It's the invocation before `fromPromise` that's the issue.

Comment: I'm following an Angular University course on rxjs - I don't intend to use fetch in any projects, but for this example I understand the http request shouldn't be happening without the subscription (according to the course author who hasn't yet come back to me). I'd really like to understand why this auto subscription is happening